# Android Studio error "requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs."

Tags: android, android-studio

2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha05' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha05' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

I have increased compileSdk, targetSdk values from 33 to 34 in build.gradle file (app level), but then when executing I had this error:

We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (8.0.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 33.

You are strongly encouraged to update your project to use a newer
Android Gradle plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34.

If you are already using the latest version of the Android Gradle plugin,
you may need to wait until a newer version with support for compileSdk = 34 is available.

To suppress this warning, add/update
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties.

Comment: Ok, and your question is ...?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I created a new empty project in Android Studio (_No activity_) using Kotlin and Minimum SDK `API 33: Android 13.0`. This will automatically set the target SDK version to `33` as well. If you then try to build (`CTRL + F9` on Windows) it will throw this error and abort building.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem.

I solved it this way from the main menu.

File/project structure/Modules/Compile SDK Version, change to 34.

Comment: Worked for me! thank you

Comment: I had to first install the API 34 SDK first.

Comment: this is the way

Answer (score 5):

Follow this path:

```
File/Project Structure/Modules/Compile SDK Version
```

and change it to `34`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me! thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem in react native. I have fixed it with using latest stable version.

I added this in app build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
      force "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You needed update:
android {
compileSdkVersion 34
...
defaultConfig {
applicationId "xxxxx"
targetSdkVersion  34 //flutter.targetSdkVersion
....
}
}
well pass issus hope help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

So i'm just learning Android Studio. Yersterday i created a project that compiled just fine, and today i started having similar errors (about using API 34 instead) with any new project and i was going totally crazy. Apparently, i don't know why, but changing the version for these dependencies in my build.gradle.kts (Module :app):

- implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.0")
- implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.0")
- implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")

To:

- implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
- implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
- implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")

And then everything worked.

Not exactly related to this error in particular, but this may be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I just use 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1' with Android Gradle plugin 8.0.2, gradle-8.0 and compileSdk/targetSdk 33.

I NEVER use alpha versions if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Update your  build.gradle app

compileSdk = letest_version

targetSdk = letest_version

`

```
compileSdk = 34

targetSdk = 34
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I think in `build.gradle` /`build.gradle.kts` can change to this:

```
compileSdk = 34
```

and

```
targetSdk = 34
```

and then in `gradle.properties` you can add at the very bottom:

```
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33,34
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options for resole this issue.

1. Downgrade androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha05' dependency
2. Upgrade your compile SDK version and compile version to 34 also update gradle plugin version. (update java sdk 11 0r later. because latest gradle versions not support older java versions )

Comment: minSDK to 34?! The app will run on devices with at least Android 14. Congratulations! No users - no problems. :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into the Gradle Scripts folder
2. Open build.gradle file
3. edit compileSdk to 34
4. [Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Vbr.png)

Comment: Wis, please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @KiranShahi this is a different user from the one who asked the question: a César Martín Muñoz Arauz.

Comment: This answer does, however, appear to repeat information that's already available in previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286088/4957508, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286974/4957508, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76454499/4957508, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/77293710/4957508, at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your expo version don't forget to change

- run `npx expo install --fix`
- change `runtimeVersion` in you config.js
- If you still get error message about the versions, delete the local android, ios file !!!DO THIS IF YOUR ARE NOT USING MODIFIED ANDROID OR IOS FILES!!!

Answer (score -1):

go to the gradle script then select build.gradle.kts(module:app) and after that inwhich update "compileSdk = 34" insteat of "compileSdk = 33"
If it is still not working update to the android studio to "Hedgehog version" then restart android studiuo and your system then again do this thing "compileSdk = 34"